# Remove space (gaps) between multiple lines of flex items when they wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a number of items underneath each other in a container with a set height. Items will then carry on next to each other if there's no space left.

This is the idea:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using flexbox, a container with a set height, direction is set to `column` and `flex-wrap` is `wrap`:

The issue is that there are wide gaps between the columns.

[image]

I tried setting both `justify-content` and `align-items` to `flex-start`, but that is probably the default value.

Is there any way to solve this?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.items {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
</div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/semajtwin/pen/WoXMWJ)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-content: stretch`.

This means that multiple lines of flex items will be distributed evenly along the cross axis.

To override this behavior, apply `align-content: flex-start` to the container.

---

When you're working in a ***single-line flex container*** (i.e., `flex-wrap: nowrap`), the properties to use to distribute space along the cross axis are `align-items` and `align-self`.

When you're working in a ***multi-line flex container*** (i.e., `flex-wrap: wrap`) – like in the question – the property to use to distribute *flex lines (rows / columns)* along the cross axis is `align-content`.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
>
> `align-items` sets the default alignment for all of the flex container’s items, including anonymous flex items. `align-self` allows this default alignment to be overridden for individual flex items.
>
> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within the
>   flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to
>   how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the main-axis.
>   *Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.*

The `align-content` property takes six values:

- `flex-start`
- `flex-end`
- `center`
- `space-between`
- `space-around`
- `stretch`

Here's the definition for `stretch`:

> ***`stretch`***
>
> Lines stretch to take up the remaining space. If the leftover free-space is negative, this value is identical to `flex-start`. Otherwise, the free-space is split equally between all of the lines, increasing their cross size.

In other words, `align-content: stretch` on the cross axis is similar to `flex: 1` on the main axis.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) Completely forgot about the `align-content` property

Comment: This was good info! It led me to try this to no effect, but then somehow I realized the issue with my single-line text having to much vertical space was that I needed to set the display property. Both `display: flex` and `display: block` works. Maybe this will help somebody else in my shoes

Answer (score 2):

to whomever this might be useful.
i just had an issue when grid (either inline-grid or inline-block) created issue with contents (buttons) that had different text lengths within them.
the result was uneven gaps between the individual grid items.
the solution came after switching to flex and modifying container and individual items as following:

```
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.grid-item {
  height: 80px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).