# Centering multiple elements with flexbox - flex-flow: row wrap puts every child in separate row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout:

```css
.app-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Noto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  margin-bottom: 84px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 304px;
  max-width: 466px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card .text {
  padding: 16px 16px 25px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
        <p>Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want to happen is for the `.card` divs to float naturally to be on the same line where there is space, but remain centered vertically and horizontaly (so the height of the cards remains the same instead of the cards expanding to fill the whole row regardless of the contet).

What happens is that if I do not set `display:inline-block;` my `.card` divs just stay one per row. But if I change the display, the centering stops working.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Put display flex on the 'cards' container (content-container)

Comment: Got rid of the content-container to not make this more confusing, still encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```css
.app-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Noto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  margin-bottom: 84px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card .text {
  padding: 16px 16px 25px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
        <p>Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
        <p>Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="text">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from the code I posted? As far as I can tell the CSS rules are the same. It also does not solve the problem of every element in the same row being the same height...

Comment: You don't want them to be the same height?

Comment: yes, I guess the question could be worded better, I'll edit it out

Comment: Hell yeah it could be better, this is in your question dude: "so the height of the cards remains the same"

Comment: Updated. Better, worse?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. So what is the difference between align-items and align-content? Or rather why did it help in my case

Comment: I believe align content is relative to container, align-items is relative to items.

Comment: `align-items` is for positioning a single line of flex items. `align-content` is used when there are multiple lines. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40890703/3597276