# How to use alignItems with flex value and wrap?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

While checking out the tutorial here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#align-items, I was unable to get the alignItems value to align the rows without any space between when I added flexWrap:'wrap' to the parent view (and enough child views such that it'd wrap). Flexbox acted as if it had a 'space-between' requirement for the rows.

```
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  }}>
  ** Enough Views to get a wrap **
</View>
```

[image: alignItems is ignored]

Setting flex:0 gets me the results I wanted:

[image: Results wanted, but I can't use flex]

The same behavior is expressed when I use flexDirection:'column', except no matter what I set the flex value to, I get the unwanted behavior:

[image: columns just never work]

Am I using flexbox incorrectly? Or is this a bug inside of react-native's flexbox?

Comment: This looks like an issue of `align-content: stretch`. But apparently there's no equivalent property in React Native. Here's a description of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40890613/3597276

Comment: Yea, I came across align-content as well. Adding alignContent:'flex-start' field to this simulator actually fixes the problem, but this solution breaks when you try it out on an actual react-native build.

Comment: related: [How does flex-wrap work with `align-self`, `align-items` and `align-content`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug with react-native, I filed a bug here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newest version of React Native [v0.43.1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.43.1), this issue is fixed and alignContent is exposed in React Native.