# Make flex items wrap to create a new column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm populating elements in a div, and I want to arrange them so it would be like this:

```
1 3
2 4
```

Right now, it's just going down

```
1
2
3
4
```

How do I tell it to move to the next column after 2 elements?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By setting a height on the container so only 2 elements fits

Comment: To be able to suggest an alternative, how many elements are we talking about and with what are they filled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a height on the container. Otherwise, how will the flex items know where to wrap?

### `height`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start; /* see notes */
  height: 50px;
}

.item {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Notes: [Remove space (gaps) between multiple lines of flex items when they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40890613/3597276)

---

### `order`

Alternatively, if you don't want to set a height on the container, you can use the `order` property.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
.item:nth-child(2) { order: 3; }
.item:nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
.item:nth-child(4) { order: 4; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

### CSS Grid

Here's another way using CSS Grid Layout:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 25px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```