# With flexbox, how do I make a list of items span over two columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

With flexbox, how do I make a list of items span over two columns?

For example:

```
2 toyota
1 mazda
8 audi
4 nissan
7 bmw
9 lexus
```

The above would be:

```
2 toyota        7 bmw   
1 mazda         9 lexus
8 audi
4 nissan
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">2 toyota</div>
  <div class="item">1 mazda</div>
  <div class="item">8 audi</div>
  <div class="item">4 nissan</div>
  <div class="item">7 bmw</div>
  <div class="item">9 lexus</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Do I need to use a flex-basis on the item class? How do I get the rest of the items from the list displayed on another column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ìtem`'s will wrap into to a new column when there is no space left for all to fit, so in this case, to force a break after the 4th, give them a 50px height.

Also, for them to be allowed to wrap, you also need to add `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 200px;
}
.container .item {
  flex-basis: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">2 toyota</div>
  <div class="item">1 mazda</div>
  <div class="item">8 audi</div>
  <div class="item">4 nissan</div>
  <div class="item">7 bmw</div>
  <div class="item">9 lexus</div>
</div>
```

---

Here is a great post dealing with possible future issues:

- [Remove space (gaps) between multiple lines of flex items when they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890613/remove-space-gaps-between-multiple-lines-of-flex-items-when-they-wrap)