# Why flexbox keep vertical space between lines?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is the layout:

```js
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "618px",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  }}
>
  <input className={"input_3"} />
  <input className={"input_3"} />
  <input className={"input_3"} />
  <input className={"input_3"} />
</div>
```

Why the upper and lower lines are not closer to each other?

[image]

```
.input_3 {
  width: 272px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 44px;
}
```

Comment: Whats input_3 class? does it have style?

Comment: hi, added input_3, nothing important

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890613/remove-space-gaps-between-multiple-lines-of-flex-items-when-they-wrap
tried it ?

Comment: use align-content property